# The Work of Pierre Deligne

Tags: soft-question

In this [biography](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Deligne.html) of Pierre Deligne, there is a quote of Jacques Tits which says that "quite a few of his best ideas have never been written!".

What are some of his best ideas that you have heard of that he hasn't written about?

Comment: Is this question appropriate for mathoverflow? I personnally believe not: what kind of answer can one expect?

Comment: I wonder how Deligne will feel if he reads that question...

Comment: The proof that the Weil conjectures implies the Ramanujan conjecture on coefficients of modular forms only exists as a Bourbaki Seminar. Serre wrote a few times (as a footnote in his Course in Arithmetic, or in his Complete Works) that he regrets this. Around 10 years ago, Brian Conrad had undertaken to write a book on the topic, but I don't think that the book has appeared (yet).

Comment: @Alain Valette: I have rewritten the question in present tense, if that was what you were commenting on.

Comment:   In trying to predict this year's prize, I searched Wikipedia for Fields medalists over 65 who hadn't yet won the Abel prize. Deligne looked like a good candidate. So then I looked for a question to ask.

Comment: This year's prize: http://www.abelprize.no/

Comment: Gowers writes: "While one never knows who will win the Abel Prize in any given year, it was virtually inevitable that Deligne would win it in due course, so today's announcement is about as small a surprise as such announcements can be." http://www.abelprize.no/c57681/binfil/download.php?tid=57753

Comment: Congratulations to Deligne on the Abel Prize, and to o-o'HO2 on predicting it!

Comment: @ o-o'HO2. Only five out of thirteen Abel prize winners are Fields medalists, so that is not a very good predictor.

Comment: The answer is clear but at least as ambigious as the question is: all best ideas which Deligne thought but kept for himself in mind and never published.

Comment: Perhaps the talk by Luc Illusie at the upcoming Deligne Day festival October 5 in New York ( see <a href="https://deligneday-morning-eorg.eventbrite.com/">Deligne Day Morning Session</a> ) will give some specific answers?